# Swagger-UI how much modification can be done

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have some questions regarding swagger-ui. I have downloaded the swagger-ui from [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and have played around with the index.html and tried modifying it. From what I understand the UI is dynamically generated based on the open api specification doc either in a yaml or json file format. My questions are as follows

1. How much modification can be done to the UI that is being generated by the Swagger?
2. Can "Try Out" functionality be modified to have more control? What I want to do is have few input fields which are not generated by swagger and use them as input for an api call, make UI more dynamic in nature.
3. Does the Swagger-UI depend on any sort of API gateway to make calls to api endpoints?

Thanks,

Salil

Answer (score 2):

> How much modification can be done to the UI that is being generated by the Swagger?

Swagger UI can be tweaked in very different ways mainly via JS or CSS.

You can have a look to https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/customization/overview/

> Can "Try Out" functionality be modified to have more control? What I want to do is have few input fields which are not generated by swagger and use them as input for an api call, make UI more dynamic in nature.

You should have a look to the link I shared above but not sure this is doable like this.

If I had to do such kind of thing I would rather look at how to complete the original OpenAPI definition (the yaml/JSON file) before passing it to Swagger UI.

Note that there is also a "interceptor" feature in Swagger UI that allow to modify requests before sending them for instance. This might interest you.

> Does the Swagger-UI depend on any sort of API gateway to make calls to api endpoints?

Not at all. Swagger UI just uses your browser to call the API at the URL documented by the OpenAPI file.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow doesn't work well when there are multiple questions as part of one "Question". Having said that, I'll answer what I know.

1. As far as I can tell, you can modify the `yaml` or `JSON` source as much as you like. You can write an entire file from scratch, or import it from any editor.
2. For this sort of testing, I think you might want to look for a more in-depth testing tool such as `Postman`. That's not something I have any experience with, but from what I hear it could help with "what if I send *this* request?" sceanrios.

Comment: Swagger UI do make call to API endpoints via regular JS code (XHR/fetch)